# Change the color of the turtle on the move

Tags: netlogo

[image]I'm writing a program about traffic in roundabouts. I have 3 colors for 3 different directions car was red car turn right, go straight green car, sky turn left. because there is one lane for turning right should not I want to change the car red car blue sky or other AU to the cars that did not go right anymore?
What function should I use to change the color of the car?

Comment: This is the code to change the color of a car `ask car [ set color red ]`. If there's something more that you need, we will need a diagram and the section of the code.

Comment: because there are other cars will perform various commands. I just want one red car number 90 turn right on the direction to turn green, and then the car would not turn right but go straight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be correct because I can't work out exactly what you need from the question, but you need to use the `with` statement to identify the correct cars. Here is something that is close to what I think you want:

```
to ...
  ...
  let to-be-red cars with [ (heading = 0 or heading = 180)
                            and distancexy 0 0 < 30
                            and ycor < -11 ]
  ask to-be-red [ set color red ]
end
```